# Error while using bcryptjs for hashing a MySql data

Tags: node.js, express, hash, bcrypt

I wish to hash my password using npm bcryptjs in expressjs file. In
**users** table, i have my email and password stored. I tried creating ***app.post*** function to hash the password and if catch any error then console log it. When i hit the API in postman, get console log error showing "***db is not a function***". i do not understand why is it showing! please help me in fixing the issue.
Just to inform, I am using Sequelize ORM.

[Given image is of mysql database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flfPO.png)

This is my server.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

//Express builds REST APIs
const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
    origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};

//cors provides Express middleware for allowing CORS with different options
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// body-parser parses the request for creating req.body object
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./models");

db.sequelize.sync();

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to Task Application." });
});

const router = require("./routes/users.routes");
app.use('/api/tutorials', router);

const router1 = require("./routes/task.routes");
app.use('/api/tasks', router1);

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.json('login')
})

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email, password } = req.body;
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
        await db('users').insert({ email: email, hash: hash });
        res.status(200).json('good')
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).send('something broke')
    }
})

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Comment: This worked in my case: db.users.build({ email: email, password: hash }).save()

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `db('users').insert({ email: email, hash: hash })` with `db.sequelize.models.users.insert({ email: email, hash: hash })`.
Also crosscheck that the Model name is `users` and not `User` in the `./models` file.

For more information: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html

Comment: It consoles, "db.sequelize.models.users.insert is not a function"

Comment: i also tried creating a function called db and when i hit the API, it consoles  "Cannot read property 'models' of undefined"

Comment: Can you share the models.js file from which you are importing the db?

Comment: i followed this tutorial https://www.bezkoder.com/node-js-express-sequelize-mysql/

Comment: This worked for me: db.users.build({ email: email, password: hash }).save()

Comment: It was all about getting hold of the reference